# Basic syntax auto-completion?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I'm quite new to PhpStorm, going from atom, sublime and aptana. 
All of these IDE's above have been able to auto complete when I write "for" it will create:

```
for ($i = 0; $i > 10; $i++) {
    //code here
}
```

And the same for writing "foreach" or even "forea" or similar. It understood what I was writing and would simply generate a template for that.

I found out that PhpStorm has something called Live Templates, and I found out that "fore" will generate a simply foreach block. But I miss for, switch and other what I would like to call "basic" code-completion.

Is there any way to enable this behavior, or a package with premade Live Templates... I've found to be quite standard in the other IDE's I've tried out for the last couple of years, so I miss this quite much.

Thanks!

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Hello, yes I know about the live templates. But for example, there is nothing for a simply for loop. Or a switch! I know I could add these myself as well, but I was wondering if there isnt a already made package or whatever containing the basics.

Comment: Well .. as you have said -- those are very basic templates .. so everybody must be just doing them themselves (if they need them, of course). AFAIK PhpStorm devs do not think (for whatever reason) that such templates are needed (otherwise they would have provided them by now) -- I do not agree with them but hey... As for "somebody else has made them" -- I've seen Live Templates for complex stuff (e.g. Laravel/Yii/Symfony/Bootstrap specific) .. but none for plain PHP (possibly because I have not looked for them -- those few that I have added myself are enough for me).

Comment: That's the original ticket -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1688 -- you can read the discussion and what was implemented. If you wish -- feel free to submit new ticket asking for more templates. I 100% agree that more out-of-the-box templates are useful to have. The only thing is -- different people have different opinions on live template names (abbreviations) and what they should actually have there. For example: it's easier for me to use my `pf` live template to have `public function ...() {}` rather than using built-in `pubf` for that.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the reply! Ok, I'll take another round of Google then. It's quite weird coming from other IDE's to PhpStorm in that regard, because most other IDE's do this. But thanks for the reply and information!

Comment: Well that second comment with the link, there seem to be my answer. This seem to really strange, but... Fair enough!